# how to determine output of complex recursive function by hand

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tail-recursion

Here's the recursive code in question:

```
def trace(a, b):
    if (a > b):
        return -1
    elif (a == b):
        print (a * a)
        return a * a
    else:
        m = (a + b) / 2
        return trace (a, m) + trace (m + 1, b)

x=trace(1,4)
```

while I'm not sure what this function is supposed to do, we are supposed to find the output of `x=trace(1,4)` along with the value of x, by hand (meaning we can't use idle to help us).

After some time, I determined that the function will print 1 and 12.25, which will be the output for when assigning x to `trace(1,4)`.

However, I do not know how to determine what the value of X will be. Although the answer is -91.75, I don't have the slightest clue how it was derived (although I know how, it would take ages to come up with this answer, and I'm not sure how we can quickly come up with the solution in a short time period such as when writing an exam).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The 8th line should be `m = (a + b) // 2`. This way, it would work the same in Python2 and Python3.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Jupp, this is definitely a Python 2 question, but can be made to work in Python 3 by correcting it your way.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I cheated. With that of my chest here are some pointers:
The function most definitely is not intended for Python 3! The reason is the / operator. In Python 2 it resulted in integers in Python3 it results floats. So bearing in mind this precondition here is my solution:

The function is not complex. The datatype of each and everyone of your variables is integer! m will always be an integer. x is 30. The recursion level is three, which equals seven calls to your function (including the first). And here is how you go about things like these: Get some paper and a pen and just write down each and every step.

1. The input is: a=1 and b=4 which leads to the else part in your function...no output so far. There m is calculated as (1+4)/2. In my book that's 2.5. But this is rounded to 2, because we have integers. Then the recursion starts with two calls (1,2) and (3,4)
2. Let's look at (1,2): a=1 and b=2. Again, no output and we go right to the else part: m is calculated as 3/2 which is a nice 1.5 rounded to 1. Again two calls of the function with new parameters (1,1) and (2, 2). Note that both calls will now enter the elif part of the function and each will produce an output and a return value. You can replace (1,1) with 1 and (2,2) with 4. The recursion is done here, and the call of trace(1,2) results in 5. Let's look at the other branch of the recursion.
3. Input is a=3 and b=4 which leads to yet another pair of calls with the following parameters: (3,3) and (4,4).
   I think by now you should get the hang of it. The fun part is to add up all the return values in the way they are provided.

As to what the function does: It sums up all the squares of all integers between a and b.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It never occurred to me if this code could be meant for Python 2. This could very well be a typo from my professor since it was meant for Python 3, which is annoying since I spent many hours trying to determine the result with pen and paper. Using integers only makes a lot more sense and makes this much easier. Thanks again!

Comment: @rexorsist: Sooo, what do you think? Is the answer acceptable, or does it lack anything?

Comment: Man, I hate it when that happens. I put quite some effort into my answer and it just won't get accepted, because a newbie does not seem to care.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at these lines:

```
m = (a + b) / 2
return trace(a, m) + ...
```

these lines only get executed if `b` is greater than `a`. That means `m` will always be greater than `a` and the first recursive function call has exactly the same problem. With the values `a = 1` and `b > a`, `m` converges to `1`. In theory, the recursion never ends since `m` will never be `1.0` or less. However, float precision is limited so there is a point (after many recursive calls) where the processor can't differ `m` from `1.0`. At this point, `elif (a == b):` becomes true and stops the recursion. That doesn't explain why the result is `-91.75`, but it shows why it is nearly impossible to show all recursive calls in a diagram or tree or sth. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to determine that towards the end, when it asks for return trace(a,m)+trace(m+1,b), that trace(a,m) will converge towards print(1), while trace(m+1,b) will converge towards print(12), which seems consistent with the result in IDLE.

I assume -91.75 comes from how many recursive calls it takes for m to be 1.0 according to IDLE. I just don't know how someone would determine this with pen and paper.